# How to get the size of a mapr-db table?

Tags: hbase, mapr

I followed following steps for creating a mapr-db table:

```
$ pwd
/mapr/cluster1/user/project

$ls
bin   src

$ maprcli volume create -name project-tables-vol -path /user/project/tables \
    -quota 100G -topology /data/rack1 

$ ls
bin   src   tables

$ hbase shell
HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
hbase(main):001:0> create '/user/project/tables/datastore', 'colfamily1'
0 row(s) in 0.5180 seconds
hbase(main):002:0> exit

$ ls -l tables
total 1
lrwxr-xr-x 1 mapr mapr 2 Oct 25 15:20 datastore -> mapr::table::2252.32.16498
```

I know table "datastore" is a link to internal mapr-db implementation. But link is always showing size 512 Bytes irrespective of amount of data in that table.

How can i get the size of data in this table in bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `maprcli table info` command:

`maprcli table info -path /mapr/my.cluster.com/user/project/tables/datastore -long`

You can find the documentation about this command here:
http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/table+info

Comment: Thanks for help. I have a followup question. When i ran this command, i got multiple columns. Though i am confused between columns "totallogicalsize" and "totalphysicalsize". Can you highlight difference between these two?

Comment: Per: https://docs.ezmeral.hpe.com/datafabric-customer-managed/73/ReferenceGuide/table-info.html  totallogicalsize Estimated size (in bytes) of uncompressed data stored in table (excluding replication).
totalphysicalsize  Estimated size (in bytes) of actual data stored in table (excluding replication).